# How to close Google OAuth pop up after server side authentication for a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I am doing a server side oAuthflow using following code(I need offline access) . Once the oAuth is done, I have to close the oAuth pop up window. on my chrome extension side. How can I close that pop up and send user back to same tab where it started the login?

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        url: https://*<my_host>*/auth/google,
        interactive: true,
  }, function(url) {
    var uri = URI(url),
        params = uri.search(true);
    var token = params.authToken;
    done(token);
  });
```

Comment: This seems like a similar issue with this [thread](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/74). This [repo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/identity) might offer additional reference

Comment: Accrding to the docs, this should be done automatically: _"When the provider redirects to a URL matching the pattern `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/*`, **the window will close**, and the final redirect URL will be passed to the callback function."_